# Laravel вывести {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Как вывести сообщение на экран?
в консоле выводит

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

но в ajax не выводит

```
$("body").on("click",'.comment--item .rcomment', function() {
        const that = $(this);
        let comment = $(this).closest('.comment--item').attr('data-id');
        let article = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        let fullname = $(this).closest('.comment--item').find('.user--link').text();
        let token = $('[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/comment/replay",
            data: { // что отправляем
                "comment":    comment,
                "fullname":   fullname,
                "article":   article,
                '_token' : token
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if (response.message){
                    alert(response.message);
                }
                if (response.error && response.error === 1){
                    toast.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: response.message
                    });
                }else {
                    $("#replay-form").fadeOut(2000).remove();
                    that.closest('.comment--item').append(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При возникновении ошибки, функция `success` не вызывается

Вам необходимо добавить функцию `error`, которая будет вызываться при возникновении ошибки

```js
$("body").on("click",'.comment--item .rcomment', function() {
        const that = $(this);
        let comment = $(this).closest('.comment--item').attr('data-id');
        let article = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        let fullname = $(this).closest('.comment--item').find('.user--link').text();
        let token = $('[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/comment/replay",
            data: { // что отправляем
                "comment":    comment,
                "fullname":   fullname,
                "article":   article,
                '_token' : token
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if (response.message){
                    alert(response.message);
                }
                if (response.error && response.error === 1){
                    toast.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: response.message
                    });
                }else {
                    $("#replay-form").fadeOut(2000).remove();
                    that.closest('.comment--item').append(response);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                toast.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: jqXHR.responseJSON.message
                });
                // TODO jqXHR.responseJSON может не быть
            }
        });
    });
```